# How can I render a partial page on click a HTML Button?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, renderpartial

I am new to MVC3.0 and have to use jquery. I as wondering some one can help with how can I render a partial view page on clicking a HTML Button?

I know it is really easy, the button could be called "email to", which will take use to a partialView called "emailForm". But I need some help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd say @smdrager's response is the desired route, if possible.  If you **need** to get html from an ajax request, however, there are *many* ways to do it... here's an example of one :)

In your template, you'd have a button or link, and a div container for your content:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="emailTo">email to</a>
<div id="emailToContent"></div>
```

You'll need some quick javascript to wire up the client-side functionality:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#emailTo").click(function(){
    $.get("<url to partial>", function(data){$("#emailToContent").html(data);}
  });
</script>
```

Then, in your controller, you need an action that returns your partial:

```
public ActionResult EmailTo()
{
  ...
  return PartialView("some partial")
}
```

Make sure the url passed into the javascript `$.get` call is pointed to the action that returns your partial.

This is a very basic implementation, which could easily get more complicated if your situation gets more complicated (exception handling, parameter passing, etc), but the general layout works for me when I need a simple ajax request to fire off.

Comment: to have even more jQuery sexiness on this, replace the ` $.get("<url to partial>", function(data){$("#emailToContent").html(data);}` with ` $("#emailToContent").load("<url to partial>";` like @smdrager wrote in his post

Answer (score 14):

You could render the page before hand, but within a hidden div, or you could use AJAX to load it after the click.

### Hidden Div

```
<div style="display:none;" id="partial">
    @Html.Partial("SomePartial")
</div>

<button type="button" id="show-partial" />
```

and a script

```
$('#show-partial').click(function(){
    $('#partial').show();
});
```

### Load with Ajax

To do this you'd create an ActionResult in a controller which renders the partial.

```
<div id="partial"></div>

<button type="button" id="load-partial" />
```

and a script

```
$('#load-partial').click(function(){
    $('#partial').load('/TheController/TheAction/');
});
```

Comment: I've never seen that `load` jquery function before... all this time I've been using `$.get` like a sucker :)

Comment: Now you know... and knowing is half the battle. J.I. JOE!